# Query builder: passing argument to anonymous function

Tags: php, laravel

I got a problem in passing variable to query builder closure, here is my code:

```
function get_usersbyname($name){
    dd($name);
    $resultset = DB::table('users')->where(function($query){
        $query->where('username', 'LIKE', $name);
    });
....
}
```

if I run it, it returns an error "`undefined name variable`", but I already passed `$name` variable and checked its existence.
Also I cann't find any resouce explains how to pass variable to query builder anonymous function.
Could you help me with this problem?

Comment: I think $name not within scope of `function($query)`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to the tell the anonymous function to use that variable like...

Because that variable is outside the scope of the annonymous function it needs to be passed in using the **use** keyword as shown in the example below.

```
function get_usersbyname($name){
    dd($name);
    $resultset = DB::table('users')->where(function($query) use ($name) {
        $query->where('username', 'LIKE', $name);
    });
....
}
```

Comment: Brilliant. I've never seen the `use` in this context. I'm also struggling to find documentation on it that doesn't refer to traits and namespaces. I'm curious how you managed to figure out this solution.